# Jquery image does not preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem is probobly simple, basically once I choose a local file it should display it on the page so that user can see how it would look like, however the image is not showing, my mouse pointer changes to indicate that computer is "working" and doing something however nothing happens

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input class="logo_upload" type='file' visibility="hidden" style="opacity: 0;" onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img class="logo_upload" id="image" src="#" alt="your image" height="60" width="60" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
}
```

How can this be solved? as I do not see any mistakes here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working `

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<div class="logo">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input class="logo_upload" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img class="logo_upload" id="image" src="#" alt="your image" height="60" width="60" />
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

/`
Maybe you have other errors that prevent js